# How to show foreign key field value instead of id in Django admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Info(models.Model)
    country_name = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
    country_code = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
    info = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

In admin interface, while adding object in 'Info' model, 'country_name' field show IDs of countries by default. But I want to show names of countries instead of IDs.

And similarly, 'country_code' field of 'Info' model also show IDs of countries by default. But I want to show codes of countries instead of IDs.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:
The value you will return from `__str__` that would be shown in admin.

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Info(models.Model)
    country_name = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
    country_code = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
    info = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.country_name.name)
```

Why are you using 2 fields for same result? Your model of Info should be:

```
class Info(models.Model)
    country_name = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)       
    info = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.country_name.code)
```

Comment: But what about 'country_code' field of Info model?

Comment: @JasmeetPabla when you linked your country model with you info with foriegn key all the field of that model also got linked with it and you can call it  like {{ info.country.name }}